# Values across multiple rows brought into one row (separate cells) if rows have matching IDs. NULL values if ID only exists once

Tags: sql, pivot, window-functions

Relatively new to Window Functions but I'm pretty sure that's what is needed here. I'm trying to combine two or more rows returned in a dataset that share the same ID/dense_rank into one row.

If there are IDs in the dataset that do not have matches within that table, there will be NULL values.

See what I would like the final results to look like and what I am currently receiving. Not sure if it would be row_number or dense_rank. Thanks! (query below).

```
select 
DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY l.unit_key) AS ID,
l.unit_key, 
l.start_date,  
u.area, 
c.amount 

from unit_rt u
    join lease_rt l on u.unit_key = l.unit_key
    join charges_rt c on l.lease_key = c.lease_key
```

[image: Current results > Desired results]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow you correctly, you can join and rank records having the same `unit_key` by ascending `start_date`, and then pivot the resultset with conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    unit_key,
    max(case when rn = 1 then l.start_date end) prior_lease_date,
    max(case when rn = 1 then u.area       end) prior_area,
    max(case when rn = 1 then c.amount     end) prior_amount,
    max(case when rn = 2 then l.start_date end) new_lease_date,
    max(case when rn = 2 then u.area       end) new_area,
    max(case when rn = 2 then c.amount     end) new_amount
from unit_rt u
inner join (
    select 
        l.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by l.unit_key order by l.start_date) rn
    from lease_rt l
) l on u.unit_key  = l.unit_key
inner join charges_rt c on l.lease_key = c.lease_key
group by l.unit_key
```

Note that this assumes either one or two records per `unit_key` only, as shown in your data.

Comment: This did function properly and produced exactly what I was looking for, so thank you for that! In an ideal situation I would want something that will be able to perform this without needing to assume anything prior.